# Force use of Azure custom domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to prevent access to my Azure website from the Azure provided domain and force the use of the custom domain via a setting/configuration within Azure?

Right now I have a custom domain associated with my Azure Web App.

So, under domain names, there are 2 listed, my custom domain and the azure provided domain.

Example:
mywebapp.com
mywebapp.azurewebsites.net

I want traffic to only be allowed in via the custom domain. So, mywebapp.azurewebsites.net should either not be allowed or should redirect to mywebapp.com.

Comment: Would someone like to elaborate on the down vote?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to change your web.config and add a URL Rewrite rule that will do a permanent redirect from the *.azurewebsites.net domain to your domain.

You can find an example on how they do that for domain.com to www.domain.com and you can apply the same logic. This [article](http://madskristensen.net/post/url-rewrite-and-the-www-subdomain) explains how to do that.

Comment: Where would the URL Rewrite rule be included? The azurewebsites.net URLs won't hit my server as they go straight to Azure, and I don't see a way to do rewrite rules like this on Azure?