# How to force Azure websites to use custom domains and not *.azurewebsites.com

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cloudflare

I have read:

[Force use of Azure custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830353/force-use-of-azure-custom-domain)

However I am routing from a WAF ie Cloudflare and want to only use the domain name ie myapp.com.

I am also asking this afresh as this was answered in 2016.

Thanks.

Comment: The approach have not changed in 2 years. You'll get your application to redirect to the domain you need if it detects that azure domain is used for access.

Comment: Thanks. very useful. For others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630536/rewriting-a-url-in-an-azure-web-app